# wanted to make sure vs wanted to be sure

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I have to write one of the following phrases into a formal correspondence (job application)

> I just wanted to **be** sure that I understood it correctly

> I just wanted to **make** sure that I understood it correctly

Which one should I use?

This is the context :

I would therefore assure you that I accept the terms and I am willing to start on 10th of June. 
I just wanted to be sure that I understood it correctly, before booking the flight.

Comment: You should add some context as to what "it" is, to confirm correct tenses are being used. Is "it" completely in the past?

Comment: This is the contest : I would therefore assure you that I accept the terms and I am willing to start on 10 th of June. 
I just wanted to be sure that I understood it correctly, before booking the flight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either "to make sure" or "to be sure" in your sentence presented, without any difference in meaning. However, according to Ngram, the former is becoming more common in the last couple of decades.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+make+sure%2C+to+be+sure&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20make%20sure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20be%20sure%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

They are pretty much equal, however, I would consider "make sure" to be a bit more direct than "be sure". "be sure" is neutral, but in:

> I want to **make sure** that you did your research properly.

there is an implication that "I" have a negative view on how "you" did something.

In the situation of a job application, I would keep it as neutral as possible.